# Fiber of Morphism between Affine Schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

My question refers to an example from 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_morphism
dealing with the morphism

$$f: {\displaystyle {\text{Spec}}(k[t,x]/(x^{n}-t))\to {\text{Spec}}(k[t])}$$

of affine schemes induced by canonic inclusion

$$\varphi: k[t] \hookrightarrow {\text{Spec}}(k[t,x]/(x^{n}-t))$$

of rings. $f$ is described as a ramified $n$-sheeted covering with only ramification at the the origin. In turn for every prime ideal $p \subset k[t]$ (= point of $Spec(k[t])$) with $p \neq (0)$ the fiber $f^{-1}(p)$ contains exactly $n$ points.

That is not clear to me, especially in the case that $k$ is not algebraically closed.

In my considerations I discuss two cases:

1. case: $k$ is algebraically closed. Therefore every prime $p \neq (0)$ has the shape $p= (t- \lambda)$ for $\lambda \in k$. Then
   $$x^n - t = \prod _{j=1} ^n (x - \zeta^j \sqrt[n]{t})$$

and therefore

$$k[t,x]/(x^n-t) \cong  \oplus _{j=1} ^n k[t,x]/(x-\zeta^j \sqrt[n]{t})$$

by CRT and we have obvoiusly exactly $n$ preimages

$$f^{-1}(p) = \{q \subset \oplus _{j=1} ^n k[t,x]/(x-\zeta^j \sqrt[n]{t}) \text{ } \vert \text{ } q \cap k[t] = p \} = \{\langle (t- \lambda), (x-\zeta^j \sqrt[n]{t})\rangle \vert 1 \le j \le n\}$$

as desired. Is this argumentation correct?

Remark: By definition for $q$ prime $f$ is defined via $f(q) = \varphi^{-1}(q) = k[t] \cap q$.

Now the case 2: $k$ is an arbitrary field.

Firstly,  we can split $x^n-t$ in $s$ to irreducible factors $f_j \in k[t,x]$ each of degree $d_i$ with $\sum _{j=1} ^s d_i =n$. Using CRT as in case 1 we get the splitting

$$k[t,x]/(x^n-t) \cong  \oplus _{j=1} ^s k[t,x]/f_j$$

Now consider an arbitrary prime ideal $p$ of $k[t]$. Since $k$ isn't algebraically closed we can't generally expect that $p$ has the shape $(t- \lambda)$.
Motivated by case 1 I think that ideals $\rangle p \cup f_i \langle $ are good candidates for preimages of $p$
since

$$q \in f^{-1}(p) \Leftrightarrow q \cap k[t] =p$$

But here I see two problems:

Firstly: This gives only $s$ preimages but according to the example
$p$ should have exactly $n$ preimages.

Secoundly: Are $\langle p \cup f_i \rangle $ prime? Why?

Remark: In this question I reduced a previous question of mine ([Ramified Cover of Affine Scheme](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3023261/ramified-cover-of-affine-scheme))
to the language of commutative algebra and trying to deduce
a formally correct argument for the statement above.

Comment: How is this question different from your previous one ? It seems also that KReiser answered it in the comment section : if $k$ is not algebraically closed, then there is not necessarily $n$ prime ideals lying above a given prime. However, if there is $g$ of then and if $f_1,...,f_g$ are the degree of their residual extensions, then $f_1+...+f_g=n$.

Comment: Think about the case of $\mathbb{R}[t]\to \mathbb{R}[t,x]/(x^2-t)$. Then there is only one prime lying above $(t+1)$ which is $(x^2+1)$. This is a prime since $\mathbb{R}[t,x]/(x^2-t,x^2+1)\simeq\mathbb{C}$. However the residual extension is $\mathbb{R}[t]/(t+1)\simeq\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}[t,x]/(x^2-t,x^2+1)\simeq\mathbb{C}$. So it is indeed of degree 2.

Comment: @Roland: I was namely quite irritated by by the the phrase 
"ramified $n$-sheeted covering" what 
I naively would interpret as a $n$-cover over all non ramified 
points. Especially that the number of
points lying over a non ramified point is constantly $n$.
So is this statement here for general field $k$ just false
or should I interpret this in the theory of schemes in another way
as for example for Riemann surfaces?

Comment: If yes, how scheme theoretically a ramified covering should be
interpreted?
In the sense that for fixed point $p$ $n$ is the sum of degrees
of field expensions $[k(q):k]$ of residual fields of all points $q$
lying over $p$ or - as in José's answer - that $f$ gives locally to
the sections a free module structure of degree $n$? ...of course that would only make sense for finite morphisms

Comment: Regarding @KReiser's answer the point that irritated me was
that he talks about $x^n -t_0$ for $t_0 \in k$ and not $x^n -t$ 
as polynomial in $k[t,x]$. Should I interpret this in the way that
when he talks about $x^n -t_0$ that he has alrady "zoomed" to the
fiber of $t- t_0$? So in the ring $k[x,t]/(x^n-t) \otimes k(p)$ for 
$k(p)= k[t]/(t-t_0)$? Or should this consideration to be interpreted 
in another way?

Comment: For KRaiser's answer, yes he looked at the fiber over $t-t_0$. He said that this is of degree $n$ over $k$. As for the interpretation of a $n$-sheeted covering, say it is really a $n$-sheeted covering if you pass to the algebraic closure. If you don't want that, say that there really is $n$ points lying above any point of the base scheme, but they might lie in an extension. If one of them does not lie in $k$, then this point and all its conjugates are tied together to form only one prime ideal, but this should count as several points instead of one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, in that example, it is obvious that $k[t,x]/(t-x^n)$ is isomorphic to $k[t]\oplus k[t]x\oplus\cdots\oplus k[t]x^{n-1}$ as $k[t]$-modules. That is all you need.

Remember the definition in Hartshorne: $f:X\to Y$ is a finite morphism if there is an affine covering of $Y$, write $Y=\bigcup U_i$, with $U_i\simeq \mbox{Spec} B_i$ such that $f^{-1}(U_i)=\mbox{Spec}(A_i)$ with $A_i$ a f.g. $B_i$-module.

Comment: Yes, the fact that $k[t,x]/(t-x^n) \cong k[t]\oplus k[t]x\oplus\cdots\oplus k[t]x^{n-1}$
as $k[t]$-module just states the fact that $f$ is a finite morphism.
My problem is to calculate here the order of the fiber $f^{-1}(p)$ for 
a prime $p$, therefore the number of primes $q$ in $k[t,x]/(t-x^n)$ 
with $p = f(q) = \varphi^{-1}(q) = k[t] \cap q$. And I think that 
for the determination of these preimages one should interpret
$\varphi$ as a ***ring map*** as well as a $k[t,x]/(t-x^n)$, since
considering it only as $k[t]$- module it makes not really sense to talk about prime 
ideals $q$.

Comment: Or did I missunderstood your thoughts?

If yes, what would here exactly the preimage of a prime $p$ wrt $f$?

Comment: aaah, okay. But, I'm agree with you, I think that if the field is not alg closed, it is not true. Have you tried in a very simple case like the field with 2 (or 3) elements?

Comment: and the characteristic dividing (or  being rel. prime with) the $n$

Comment: Yes, that is wrong, see @Roland's example above. 
Futhermore I think that base change to algebraic closure as Roland also explained indeed seem to provide a good interpretation of ramified n
-sheeting in ag